# Rendering a rectangle with multiple classes

Tags: java, graphics

I am making a simple game project and I am having a problem when trying to create a rectangle that moves across the screen.
Here is the main class:

`public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private JFrame frame;
boolean running = false;

Graphics g;

static int HEIGHT = 500;
static int WIDTH = HEIGHT * 16 / 9;

SoundHandler sh = new SoundHandler();

//Game state manager
private GameStateManager gsm;

public Main()
{
    //window
    frame = new JFrame("Game");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    init();
}

void init()
{
    gsm = new GameStateManager();
    sh.playMusic("Undertale.wav", 1);
}

public synchronized void start(){
    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public synchronized void stop(){
    running = false;
}

//game loop
public void run() 
{
    //init time loop variables
    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();
    final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
    final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
    double lastFpsTime = 0;
    int fps = 0;

    while(running)
    {
        //work out how long its been since last update
        //will be used to calculate how entities should
        //move this loop
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;
        double delta = updateLength / ((double)OPTIMAL_TIME);

        //update frame counter
        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        fps++;

        //update FPS counter
        if(lastFpsTime >= 1000000000)
        {
            System.out.println("FPS " + fps);
            lastFpsTime = 0;
            fps = 0;
        }

        //game updates
        update(delta);

        //draw
        draw(g);

        try{
            Thread.sleep((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME)/1000000 );
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Error in sleep");
        }
    }
}

private void update(double delta)
{
    //updates game state code
    gsm.update(delta);
}

public void draw(Graphics g)
{
    gsm.draw(g);
}`
```

here is the class I want to draw the rectangle with

```
package me.mangodragon.gamestate;
```

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class MainState extends GameState{

```
int x;

public MainState(GameStateManager gsm){
    this.gsm = gsm;
}

public void init() {

}

public void update(double delta) {
    x += 2 * delta;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawRect(x, 0, 50, 50);
    g.dispose();
}

public void keyPressed(int k) {

}

public void keyReleased(int k) {

}
```

}
I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
at me.mangodragon.gamestate.MainState.draw(MainState.java:22)
at me.mangodragon.gamestate.GameStateManager.draw(GameStateManager.java:37)
at me.mangodragon.main.Main.draw(Main.java:118)
at me.mangodragon.main.Main.run(Main.java:100)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I tried to fix it, but I could not locate the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You never assign anything to `g` (`Graphics`). Now, before you run off and try and figure out how you might do that, I'd highly, highly recommend you get rid of this variable, it's going to cause you too many issues.

Normally, when the system wants your component to painted, it calls your `paint` method and passes you the `Graphics` context which it wants you to paint to.  This approach is known as passive painting, as the paint requests come at random times, which isn't really what you want.  Another issue is `java.awt.Canvas` isn't double buffered, which will cause flickering to occur as your component is updated.

You might want to take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

You could use a `JPanel` instead, which is double buffered, but the main reason for using `java.awt.Canvas` is so you can make use the [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) API.  This not only provides double buffering, but also provides you with a means by which you can take direct control over the painting process (or active painting).

See [`BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You defined `g` as such:

```
Graphics g;
```

But never gave it a value.

This is not how you should be drawing shapes, anyways.  Instead, override the paint method (inherited from Canvas) in class `Main`:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    //Drawing code goes in here.  This runs whenever the Canvas is rendered.
}
```

Then, when you want to update it, such as in your `while` loop, run

```
this.repaint();  //note that this doesn't take arguments
```

If you want to use the `draw(Graphics g)` method in the other class, call it in `paint()`.

```
public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    gsm.draw(g);
}
```

Comment: Why technically correct, the reason for using Canvas is so you can make use the BufferStrategy, which provides direct control over the painting process as well as providing double buffering, which isn't included using you suggested approach. So the answer is, either use a JPanel (and paintComponent) or a BufferStratgey

Comment: Oh, right, I'm more used to using JPanel than Canvas.  Sorry about that!  @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have not defined `g`, so it is null. And for the most part, you are never supposed to create a new `Graphics` object, but instead get it from somewhere.

Since you are inheriting a `Canvas`, this can be very easily done.

First, you should change your `draw` method to be like this.

```
private void draw() {
    BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        this.createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    // Draw your game here, using the g declared above
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

The first few lines create something called a `BufferStrategy` which you can read more about [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) but it essentially lets Java render the next couple frames ahead of schedule so that you don't see any flickering.

From the `BufferStrategy`, you can get the `Graphics` object to draw on.

And, finally, you have to dispose of the `Graphics` object, and then show the `Buffer` so that everything you did shows on the screen.